# Pagination with filter

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, e-commerce

I am currently working on a React application where I am facing challenges in implementing filtered pagination for a product listing page. My goal is to display filtered content to users with pagination based on applied filters. The backend is successfully providing filtered products, but I am encountering difficulties in synchronizing and implementing pagination according to these filters.

Below, I am providing snippets of code from different React components related to the product page of my website:

App.jsx :

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './views/Home'
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar"
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
import Loading from './components/Loading'
import LoginSignup from './views/LoginSignup'
import Products from './views/Products'
import Product from './views/Product'
function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route exact path='/loading' element={<Loading/>} />
        <Route exact path='/login' element={<LoginSignup/>} />
        <Route exact path='/products/' element={<Products/>} />
        <Route exact path='/product/' element={<Product/>} />
        <Route path='/products/:keyword' element={<Products/>} />
      </Routes>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};

export default App
```

Products.jsx :

```
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
import ProductCard from '../components/ProductCard'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts , productsSelecter} from "../slices/productSlice";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate';

const Products = () => {
  const dispatch  = useDispatch();
  const {products, loading, hasErrors, total, count, filterCount} = useSelector(productsSelecter);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const keyword =""
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching products with page:", currentPage);
    dispatch(fetchProducts(keyword, currentPage));
  }, [dispatch, currentPage, keyword]);
  
  return (
    <div className='min-h-svh py-24 dark:bg-black gap-4 bg-gray-100 flex '>
      <section className='w-1/5 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-3xl ml-6'>
        <Sidebar />
      </section>
      <section className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-10'>
        <h1 className='text-slate-500 border-b-2 w-1/3 text-xl text-center'> PRODUCTS</h1>
      <div className=" grid grid-cols-4 gap-10 flex-grow px-20  h-[100svh]">
        {
          products.map((product) =>(
            <ProductCard key={product.name} {...product} />
          ))
        }

      </div>
        <div>
        <Paginate
        currentPage={currentPage}
        setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
        total={total}
        count={count}
      />

        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products
```

SideBar.jsx :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProducts } from '../slices/productSlice';

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyword.trim()) {
      navigate(`/products/${keyword}`);
      dispatch(fetchProducts(keyword, 1));
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      dispatch(fetchProducts(keyword, 1));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-6 items-center justify-center'>
      <section>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Search Products....'
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
          className='bg-gray-100 outline-none rounded-full px-2 py-2 mt-4'
        />
      </section>
      <section>
        <p className='font-mono'>Filters</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Pagination.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';

const Paginate = ({ currentPage, setCurrentPage, total, count }) => {
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(total / count);
  const pageNumbers = Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, index) => index + 1);

  return (
    <div className='w-full'>
      <ul className='flex gap-3 items-center justify-center'>
        <li
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.max(prevPage - 1, 1))}
          className='cursor-pointer w-20 dark:text-slate-200 text-center hover:bg-violet-600 hover:text-white py-1 px-2 rounded-full'
        >
          Previous
        </li>

        {pageNumbers.map((page) => (
          <li
            key={page}
            onClick={() => setCurrentPage(page)}
            className={` w-7 dark:text-slate-200 text-center rounded-sm  cursor-pointer ${currentPage === page ? 'bg-violet-500 text-white' : ''}`}
          >
            {page}
          </li>
        ))}

        <li
          onClick={() => setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.min(prevPage + 1, totalPages))}
          className='cursor-pointer dark:text-slate-200 w-20 text-center hover:bg-violet-600 hover:text-white py-1 px-2 rounded-full'
        >
          Next
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Paginate;
```

productSlice.js :

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const initialState = {
    loading:false,
    hasErrors:false,
    total:undefined,
    count:undefined,
    filterCount:undefined,
    products:[],
};

const productSlice = createSlice({
    name:'products',
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        getProducts:(state) => {
            state.loading = true
        },
        getProductsSuccess: (state, {payload}) => {
            state.products = payload.products
            state.count = payload.resultPerPage
            state.total = payload.productsCount
            state.filterCount = payload.filterCount
            state.loading=false
            state.hasErrors = false
        },
        getProductsFailure:(state) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.hasErrors = true
        }
    }
})

export const {getProducts, getProductsSuccess, getProductsFailure} = productSlice.actions;
export const productsSelecter = (state) => state.products

export function fetchProducts(keyword="", currentPage=1){
    return async(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getProducts());
        try{
            const url = `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}`
            const response = await axios.get(url)
            const data = response.data

            dispatch(getProductsSuccess(data))
        }catch(error){
            dispatch(getProductsFailure(error.message))
        }
    }
}

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

I am seeking advice on how to efficiently achieve filtered pagination, ensuring that users can navigate through the paginated results based on the applied filters. Your insights and guidance will be greatly appreciated. Please provide some working code if possible to replicate the process.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.